# Integers still coming out random? Basic coding error. C

Tags: c

For homework we have to come up with a program that looks at how many game credits a person has, how much game two different powerups cost and figures out how many powerups you can buy using the credits you have. I figured the program simply picks the powerup that costs less and divides the total number of credits by whatever that amount is.

I think the math is right? Though the integers in the last printf always come out random as if they aren't reading anything at all. There's probably a glaring issue that i just can't see because i don't know enough yet.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    //listen for cost of first powerup
    int powerone;
    printf("How much does the first powerup cost (in credits)?\n");
    scanf("%d", &powerone);

    //listen for cost of second powerup
    int powertwo;
    printf("How much does the second powerup cost (in credits)?\n");
    scanf("%d", &powertwo);

    //listen number of credits
    int credits;
    printf("How many credits do you currently have?\n");
    scanf("%d", &credits);

    //figure out how many powerups you can get
    int answer;
    {
        if (powerone > powertwo) {
            int answer = credits / powertwo;
        }
        else if (powerone < powertwo) {
            int answer = credits / powerone;
        }
        else if (powerone == powertwo) {
            int answer = credits / powerone;
        }
    }

    int LEFTOVER;
    {
        if (powerone > powertwo) {
            LEFTOVER = credits - (answer * powertwo);
        }
        else if (powerone < powertwo) {
            LEFTOVER = credits - (answer * powerone);
        }
        else if (powerone == powertwo) {
            LEFTOVER = credits - (answer * powerone);
        }
    }

    printf(" You can purchase a maximum of %d powerups, with %d credits left over.\n", answer, LEFTOVER);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at *variable scope* in C.

Every time you've written `int answer`, you're creating (and then usually discarding) a new variable that happens to have the same name as one at a higher scope.

```
int answer = 1;
if (true)
{
    int answer = 2; // Seperate variable, which disappears at the close brace
}
// answer still equals 1

int LEFTOVER= 1;
if (true)
{
    LEFTOVER= 2; // Correct! Accessing LEFTOVER that already exists.
}
// LEFTOVER now equals 2
```

The random numbers are because if you just declare a variable without setting a value in C and C++ (`int answer;`)  it just leaves whatever random bits happened to be in that space in memory beforehand.

At the level of coding you're doing, it's pretty much always worth initialising variables with either a sensible default, or an obvious error code like `int answer = -1`.

Comment: ah gosh i totally missed that wow... Thanks a bunch! Code works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
//listen for cost of first powerup
    int powerone;
    printf("How much does the first powerup cost (in credits)?\n");
    scanf("%d", &powerone);
//listen for cost of second powerup
    int powertwo;
    printf("How much does the second powerup cost (in credits)?\n");
    scanf("%d", &powertwo);
//listen number of credits
    int credits;
    printf("How many credits do you currently have?\n");
    scanf("%d", &credits);
//figure out how many powerups you can get
   int answer = 0;
   if (powerone > powertwo) {
        answer = credits / powertwo;
    }
    else if (powerone < powertwo) {
        answer = credits / powerone;
    }
    else if (powerone == powertwo) {
        answer = credits / powerone;
    }

    int LEFTOVER = 0;    
    if (powerone > powertwo) {
        LEFTOVER = credits - (answer * powertwo);
    }
    else if (powerone < powertwo) {
        LEFTOVER = credits - (answer * powerone);
    }   
    else if (powerone == powertwo) {
        LEFTOVER = credits - (answer * powerone);
    }    
printf(" You can purchase a maximum of %d powerups, with %d credits left over.\n", answer, LEFTOVER);

return 0;

}
```

Since you are using variable answer common for all condition there is no need to declare it again. You should declare it only once and should also initialize it to 0. same goes with Leftover variable.

Try to run this it will work.